# Why is DemoBaseApplLayer::myId different in Veins versions 4.7.1 and 5.0?

Tags: omnet++, veins

In Veins 5.0, the `myId` member accessible from, e.g., `TraCIDemo11p::initialize(int stage)`, refers to the OMNeT++ module ID of the NIC (e.g., `node[0].nic`).

In Veins 4.7.1, `myId` used to refer to the OMNeT++ module ID of the host (e.g., `node[0]`).

Why was this changed?

Comment: As the initialize mehthod is from OMNeT and not from Veins, I suggest you to become familiar with the basics of OMNeT++. For example try the TicToc tutorial.

Comment: I already did the TicToc tutorial. But in VEINS, there is something different about the result of the myId variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Veins is now supporting multiple NICs (as well as unicast communication via 802.11p), it makes sense to use a per-NIC identifier for addressing hosts on the application layer. This has therefore become the new default in Veins 5.0.

The exact change (and how to revert it, if desired), is documented in the version history. It can be accessed, e.g., via https://github.com/sommer/veins/blame/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc#L83